# Finding surrounding line of Keyword in HP-UNIX

Tags: unix, grep

I want to see 5 lines befor and after the 'Keyword',but i am getting this error.
I am working on HP-UNIX.
Can any one help me with this one?
Thanks

Command:`grep -C 5 Keyword file_name`

Error:

```
grep: illegal option -- C
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvx] -e pattern_list...
        [-f pattern_file...] [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvx] [-e pattern_list...]
        -f pattern_file... [file...]
usage: grep [-E|-F] [-c|-l|-q] [-bhinsvx] pattern [file...]
```

Comment: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch27_11.htm

Comment: Can you try this `grep -B 5 -A 5 Keyword file_name` (B=Before A=After)?

Comment: OP says he's working on HP unix - -B will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an `awk` that emulate `grep -C 5`

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} $0~s {f=NR} END {for (i=f-C;i<=f+C;i++) print a[i]}' C=5 s="Keyword" file_name
```

PS! does only work with one hit.

---

This should emulate `grep -C 5` for more hits. (some complicate due to array sort missing)

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} $0~s {f[NR]++} END {for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) if (f[j]) for (i=j-C;i<=j+C;i++) print a[i]}' C=5 s="Keyword" file_name
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you like the answer, you can accept it by click on the check mark to the left of the post :)